# Initialize size of array base from input in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, initialization, size

So I'm having a problem with passing values to another class in java. 
I have an application which accepts an equation from the user, after the button gets clicked, it finds out the number of variables the equation has and I'm putting the variables in two lists. Now, I need to pass these variables to another class.

here's the snippet of code where I need to use the variables:
beeColony.java

```
public class beeColony {
int D;
double Foods[][]=new double[FoodNumber][D];
public void getDimension(int D)
    {
        this.D = D;
    }
}
```

based from here, I need to initialize the variable Foods into having a size depending on the FoodNumber and D. There's no problem w/ regards to the FoodNumber since it is a static one.

in my main application there is an event handler

```
private void getvalueMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    bee.getDimension(dim);
}
```

when I output the variable D in one of my methods, it is equal to the value that I assigned it to. My problem is that the size of array Foods. I get an IndexOutOfBounds Exception. I think that when I initialize the array Foods, it is unable to get the value of D.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using getDimension() to set a value?

The reason this is happening is because you must have created a new class of beeColony and while doing that you used the default value of D (set to zero). It would then use this value of D to create the Foods array. This would create a Foods array of size FoodNumber x 0

I would change it as follows:

```
public class beeColony {
   int D;
   double Foods[][]=null;
  public void getDimension(int D)
    {
       this.D = D;
       this.Foods = new double[FoodNumber][D];
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: I'm using getDimension to set the value of D in class beeColony to the dimension based on user's input. Your solution works great, thank you very much! I was trying to use this.Foods = new Double[FoodNumber][D] earlier but I was getting an error. Maybe it was because the way I initialized Foods. What I did was double Foods[][]; Thank you again!